# A question regarding isomorphism of group rings

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, finite-groups, noetherian, group-rings

> For a ring with unity $R$ and a group $G$ let $R[G]$ denote the group ring. Now let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with unity such that $R[\mathbb Z_m] \cong R[\mathbb Z_n]$ (isomorphic as rings); then is it true that $m=n$ ? If not true for commutative Noetherian rings, is it at least true for commutative artinian rings ?

UPDATE: The counterexample by @anon in the comment shows that the claim is false in general for  commutative rings (not Noetherian). On the other hand the claim is true for $R=\mathbb Z$, and in fact a result of Graham Higman states that if $G,H$ are finite abelian groups such that $\mathbb Z [G] \cong \mathbb Z[H]$  then $G \cong H$ .

Comment: Is $R[\Bbb Z_m]\cong R[\Bbb Z_n]$ an isomorphism of rings or $R$-algebras?

Comment: @anon : as rings only

Comment: Counterexample in the general case: $R=S[G]$ where $G$ is a $\bigoplus$ of $\omega$-many $\Bbb Z_m$s and $\Bbb Z_n$.

Comment: @anon : What would happen if I wanted algebra isomorphism ?

Comment: @misao, if you look at algebras, then an isomorphism implies the two group rings have the same rank over R, and if R is commutative, then the groups have the same order.

Comment: @Mariano Suarez-Alvarez : yes definitely . I observed this just after posting my comment but somehow forgot to mention it afterwards. Anyway thank you for your attention . The ring isomorphism case looks much more difficult ...